What does == operator do for multisets?
In the following program:
#include <set>

int main() {

  std::multiset<int> sc1;
  std::multiset<int> sc2;

  bool isEqual = sc1 == sc2;
}

What does the == sign check? How does it work?

It uses the overloaded operator== to compare the contents of the two multisets. Note that finding and  reading right documentation is important part of programming.

While I don't find this question particularly useful, it currently has 2 close votes for "Needs more focus". It's beyond my mental abilities to comprehend how this question could be any more focused, and still be a question. Perhaps one of the close voters could explain how this could be more focused?

@cigien With an electron microscope?

@cigien I think this should be reopened. I've voted to reopen.

"Needs more focus" is a correct close reason when more than one question is being asked.  I would also say "How does it work?" very likely needs more focus.  How do functions work?  That's a book.

@DrewDormann I'm not seeing multiple questions here. Yes, there are 3 question marks, but it's a stretch to claim they're asking different things. And how are you interpreting this question as asking "How do functions work?"? It's asking how a specific function works.


what does the == sign checks

It compares the contents of the two multisets using the overloaded operator==. In sc1 == sc2, the contents of sc1 and sc2 are compared.
From operator==:

template< class Key, class Compare, class Alloc >
bool operator==( const std::multiset<Key, Compare, Alloc>& lhs,
                const std::multiset<Key, Compare, Alloc>& rhs );   (1)

Compares the contents of two multisets.


sc1 == sc2 compares the 2 std::multisets using operator== (a non-member function) and returns true if their content is the same.
More formally as you can see in cppreference:

template< class Key, class Compare, class Alloc > bool operator==(
    const std::multiset<Key, Compare, Alloc>& lhs,
    const std::multiset<Key, Compare, Alloc>& rhs );

Checks if the contents of lhs and rhs are equal, that is, they have
the same number of elements and each element in lhs compares equal
with the element in rhs at the same position.

